# How to fix React hook form Controller defaultValue type warning in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I am using [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started/#IntegratingwithUIlibraries) with [react-select](https://react-select.com/home) using typescript.

```
     <Controller
              name="year"
              control={control}
              defaultValue={yearOptions[0]}
              render={({ field }) => (
                <SingleSelect
                  label="Select Release Year"
                  styles={noDotColourStyles}
                  data={yearOptions}
                  field={field}
                  errorMessage={errors.year?.message}
                />
              )}
            />
```

Here is the `SingleSelect.tsx` component.

```
export const SingleSelect: FunctionComponent<SingleSelectProps> = (props: SingleSelectProps) => {
  const { label, data, styles, field, errorMessage } = props;
  return (
    <FieldWrapper label={label} errorMessage={errorMessage}>
      <Select
        defaultValue={data[0]}
        options={data}
        styles={styles}
        instanceId={label}
        id={label}
        {...field}
        aria-label={label}
        aria-labelledby={label}
      />
    </FieldWrapper>
  );
};
```

I am trying to display `defaultValues` and everything works as expected. But there is a type error on the

```
     <Controller
              name="year"
              control={control}
              defaultValue={yearOptions[0]}
```

[image: typeError]

Here is the shape of DataOption:

```
export interface DataOption {
  readonly value: string;
  readonly label: string;
  readonly color: string;
}
```

And here is the example of `yearOptions`

```
export const yearOptions: readonly DataOption[] = [
  { value: '2022', label: '2022', color: '#00B8D9' },
  { value: '2021', label: '2021', color: '#0052CC' },
  { value: '2020', label: '2020', color: '#5243AA' },
  { value: '2019', label: '2019', color: '#FF5630' },
]
```

Here is the data after I submit the form and the UI.

UI:

[image: UI]

console data:

[image: console data]
**BUT**
If I change the values from `defaultValue={yearOptions[0]}` to `defaultValue={yearOptions[0].value}` the error goes way.

`onSubmitting the form` I get this yup error.

```
year must be a `object` type, but the final value was: `null` (cast from the value `"2022"`). If "null" is intended as an empty value be sure to mark the schema as `.nullable()`
```

So, I have changed the `yup` schema to use `nullable` from

```
    year: yup
      .object()
      .shape({
        value: yup.string(),
        label: yup.string(),
        color: yup.string(),
      })
      .required('Year is required'),
```

to

```
    year: yup
      .object()
      .shape({
        value: yup.string(),
        label: yup.string(),
        color: yup.string(),
      })
      .nullable()
      .required('Year is required'),
```

So now the yup `nullable` error is gone, but it **does not take the default values**.
[image: no default values]

How to make `react-hook-form` accept `defaultValues` of custom types?